# Refrence XSD in XSLT file and match on element name to get element type

Tags: xslt

I am a beginner in using XSLT so I am not sure if this is even feasible. I really appreciate your help.

XSLT to transform from one format to another.
The source XML does not have the type.

I need to reference the XSD to get the type for the given element.

```
<match="*[not(*)]">
    <elementName>
       <key>
         <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
       </key>
       <type>
         if (name() matches name =id in xsd file" 
         // if name = id matches name = id in xsd get type=String

       <type>
```

This is sample XSD:

```
    <xs:complexType name = "test">
    <xs:sequence
    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xscomplexType>
```

Comment: Your question is too sloppy to enable an answer. Please post **complete** examples of your XML, XSLT and XSD - see: [mcve]. -- Also state if your XSLT processor supports XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Using an XSLT 2.0 schema-aware transformation, you can write:

```
<xsl:import-schema>
  ... schema goes here, either inline or by reference ...
</xsl:import-schema>

<xsl:template match="element(id, xs:string)">
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

The normal way of using this assumes that you write your stylesheet knowing what is in the schema. Saxon has extended this with extension functions allowing you to discover what is in your schema. For example:

```
<xsl:variable name="type" select="saxon:type-annotation()"/>
<key><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></key>
<type>Q{<xsl:value-of select="namespace-from-QName($p)||"}"||local-name-from-QName($type)"/></type>
```

See the saxon:type-annotation and saxon:schema extension functions at http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon

Analysing a schema document from XSLT directly is possible in theory but it's an enormous amount of work to get it right, if you're going to handle things such as xs:include/import/redefine, named types and anonymous types, global and local element declarations, substitution groups, etc. etc.

Yet another approach is to analyse the "precompiled schema" in XML format (SCM) which you can output from Saxon, which eliminates many of these difficulties.

Other products also offer APIs to access the schema, but there is no real standard.